# Need to integrate Informatica with Hive

Tags: hadoop, informatica

I am trying to integrate IBM Informatica with hive table to take advantage on ETL processing capabilities of Informatica and data storage abilities of Hive (Hadoop) together.
Could you guys please suggest how I can achieve this?
a. Directly refer to hive tables as source identifiers in Informatica?
b. Data processed by Informatica should be stored into HDFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JDBC connector for hive to process data to and fro from Hive to Information
https://network.informatica.com/onlinehelp/analyst/961HF3/en/index.htm#page/analyst-tool-guide/GUID-3849D181-CE1C-4EFC-8B40-076762C57817.1.19.html .

Comment: Thanks vinodamz.. I will try this approach.